# Battery indicator increase when not charging

Tags: battery, charging

Basically, two hours ago my battery level is at 8%, then an hour ago, it was at 9%. Now it's at 10%. Why is it going up even though it is not plugged in? Would I need to calibrate my battery?

**Note: This is a new phone**

Comment: When you are not using your phone it happens

Answer (score 5):

Battery app re-calculates the remaining battery based on the battery power currently being used (mV) and history. That's why you can do calibration to correctly measure the current battery status and range of it.

In most case, battery power (mV), it goes down from the top and it usually up & down within a small range but for overall, it goes down.
But sometimes, the current mV is goes up and it's caused by
1. Battery usage forecast was wrong or
2. Battery is recovering its power again - for example, after CPU intensive task, the voltage could goes up
3. the remaining percentage goes up if the battery usage is slower than the expectation (it's not going up because it's not being used. Even the screen is off, the battery is still being used). In this case battery app recalculate the percentage based on the current mV and trend that how fast battery mV is decreasing. If mV is increasing, then battery app will show like it's being charged...
But actually its not being charged, instead battery app recalculates the mV decreasing speed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense. Would you be able to point to some references also?